# CSS menu auto-clicking first item when tapping switcher on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive CSS menu at the following site: http://eurogoldendoodle.com. It uses a switcher on mobile. But there is one problem. When I open the switcher/hamburger menu on mobile, it seems to register a second click to the first item in the menu, which is the Home button. This makes it instantly GO to the home page immediately once you open the menu.

If I set the link for this menu item to "#", it works perfectly. Except then I lose the home link!

So basically, it is opening the switcher menu and clicking on the first item at the same time, which means I don't have a chance to navigate through the menu to find the link I want.

I realize that CSS doesn't have an "onClick" event and other tools I could use, but surely I must be missing something? Is it possible to do this using only CSS? If not, then what is the easiest and lightest way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing a little bit, but I suspect you need to move your list items down a bit so the first one doesn't get clicked.

Try;

```
.sky-mega-menu li {
    padding-top: 55px;
}
```

in your mobile stylesheet only!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I couldn't quite get it to act right using the padding, but your idea gave me another solution. I basically added an additional EMPTY menu item with a 0 padding and width, but a 55px height. So it took up no additional space in the desktop menu, but the height allows the mobile version to be pushed down!

So while your solution didn't work for me(I may have been messing something up, as it is very late), it got me to where I needed! Thanks!